# [SQL]A table is displayed in Ascending order on basis of a column.when two records have same data ,display them in Descending based on another column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i have a table with two column:

| brandName | model |
| --- | --- |
| Ninja | TY |
| Fiat | Mx-23 |
| ferrari | Ap0 |
| Audi | Wp |
| Tesla | X |
| ferrari | Fp0 |
| Ninja | PX |
| ferrari | U20 |

i want the table to be displayed in ascending order on the basis of brand name . but when the brandname is repeated/same[eg ferrari,Ninja] for those records i want them to be in the order of descending based on their  model when being displayed.

Comment: Hint: try using ORDER BY

Comment: @NickW i know how to order by ascending order on basis of brand name , but not  further  order by descending on basis of model when brand name for two record is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want two order by keys:

```
order by brandname, model desc
```